# What do I return instead of a std::shared_ptr<>&?

Tags: c++, memory, game-development

I am trying to make a game and in the world class I am trying to return a shared_ptr refrence. But what can I return this is the code below:

```
std::shared_ptr<Entity>& World::GetEntity(const ID::Entity& id)
{
    for (auto& obj : entities)
        if (obj->GetID() == id)
            return obj;
    return /*What?*/;
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth to consider if returning a reference is a good idea. Ref means - "kind of a pointer but mostly never-null pointer". If I undestand your intention here- retunring pointer to an entiry by ID is a effectifve `find` operation. And it may just so happen that there is no entiry with a given id. This is the essence of your question. There are multiple ways to aproach it: 
- return a shared_ptr to an entity on shared_ptr{} -(effectively null pointer) in case no object is found.
- Use std::optional.

Comment: You could have a class static empty shared_ptr to return a reference to. But I wouldn't consider this if you can't return a const reference.

Comment: If ownership is supposed to be shared with the caller, return by value. If ownership is supposed to be shared but not with the caller, return a raw pointer. If `World` is the sole owner of the entities, you should be using `unique_ptr` and return a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: In this case don't use ref as a return type. Return `shared_ptr<Entity>` by value. Consider returning `shared_ptr<Entity>{}` - if no entity found. Better yet - `optional<shared_ptr<Entity>>`

In C++ reference is equivalent of using a pointer that is almost never null. So your code effectively returns a pointer to a pointer. It does look redundant. 
Note that `shared_ptr<>` - does have ownership semantic. This means that returning `shared_ptr<>` value - not a ref. - means that caller of `World::GetEntity` - will have a pointer to an entity and shared ownership of that entity.

Also note: `World::GetEntity` effectively a *find* operation. And it may just so happen that there is no entity with a given id. This is the essence of your question. 
There are multiple ways to approach it:

- Return a shared_ptr to an entity - instead of a ref to pointer. return shared_ptr{} -(effectively null pointer) in case no entity is found.
- Use std::optional<> to communicate explicitly to your method callers that there may be a case of no result.

Comment: I Totaly forgot about std::optional<>, thanks i got for 1hour